# How to stop the KeyError being given in console

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have written this piece of code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    for i in _dict_love[message.content]:
        message_love_return = 1
        print("true")
        break

    if message_love_return == 1:
        await bot.add_reaction(message, '\N{HEAVY BLACK HEART}')
```

Basically what it does is checks to see if the message input sent from someone in Discord is in `_dict_love` and then adds an emoji to their message. The code is works, except every time someone sends a message that IS NOT in `_dict_love` it throws the following error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\Programing\woopyBot_pack\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/Programing/woopyBot_pack/main.py", line 44, in on_message
    for i in _dict_love[message.content]:
KeyError: 'banana'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well what *should* happen if it's not in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may return empty list `[]` using `dict.get` and then use that with `for` loop as:

```
for i in _dict_love.get(message.content, []):
    # do something
```

---

**Explanation:** Here, if `message.content` key will not be present in `_dict_love` dict, `_dict_love.get(message.content, [])` will return empty list.

Comment: Thank you very much! And thanks for explaining how it works

Comment: I appreciate your answer as it did help, but I also found this which checks if any of the words contained in the `message.content` are in the `dict` `any(st in message.content for st in _dict_love):`

Comment: I am not sure that I understood what you just mentioned. Based on the code you mentioned in comment, it *checks for presence of any of key of `_dict_love` dict  in `message.content` string*. But how is it related to question is the thing which I doubt.